# Add lightning component as custom tab for all Apps

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom, tab

Here is documentation about Add Lightning Components as Custom Tabs in Lightning Experience.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_add_cmp_lex.htm

However, when I add as above, I can see the tab only when I open App louncher, then select our app. Actually, it is added to app launcher as an app. Than I can see and select tab there.

I want my component's tab is shown in all apps, no matter what I choose from App Launcher.

Is it possible?

NOTE: I also should set some attributes of my component to work properly. But adding it according to documentation, I cannot set attributes.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want, if it is an independent app - maybe the [Utility Bar](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/204/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/utility_bar_impl_guide.pdf) will help you

Comment: @ItaiShmida I am developing an app for salesforce, and for SF classic I can add a custom tab related to my app. When a user download my app, a custom tab also added to tabs. However, when I add a custom tab to lightning as in documentation above, my custom tab is seen only Sales.app is selected from App Launcher. I want my custom tab is seen always no matter which app is selected from App Launcher.